# What is the correct way to use SWRevealViewController and Swift?

Tags: swift, ios8, swrevealviewcontroller

What is the right way to use SWRevealViewController with Swift?  XCode: 6.0.1
I am even having trouble important the file properly :/

[image]

MenuViewController.swift

```
import UIKit
import SWRevealViewController

class MenuViewController: SWRevealViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

If someone has a small github they could point me to I would really appreciate it!

Comment: Did you figure it out? could you share your knowledge? :)

Answer (score 6):

In order to access your Objective C classes from your Swift code, you'll need a bridging header. Apple has a good explanation here:

[Swift and Objective-C in the Same Project](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html)

Once you have the bridging header:

1. add `#import "SWRevealViewController.h"` to the bridging header file
2. there is no step 2, your class is now available to all your swift code in that target.
3. profit?

Answer (score -1):

You will have to create a Bridging header file to access all the objective C files in swift. Once you have created the Bridging header, all your import statements would be written inside the bridging header as

## import "SWRevealViewController.h"

You don't have to write the import statements individually in each file as you used to write in Objective C. Once you include the #import statement in the Bridging-Header file, you will be able it in the entire project.